# Perl: String Repetition Operator in Substituion Regex

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

Is there an easy way to use Perl's repetition operator, `x`, during a substitution regex?

I'm trying to do a quick one-liner on very basic HTML without using a module. Essentially, I'd like to transform lines with opening `<h*>` and closing `</h*>` HTML tags into WIKI markup based on the heading number in the HTML tag.  So...

`___Original DATA___`

- `<h1> This is a header one</h1>`
- `<h2> This is a header two</h2>`
- `<h3> This is a header three</h3>`

`___Wanted DATA___`

- `= This is a header one =`
- `== This is a header two ==`
- `=== This is a header three ===`

Everything works well with the regex itself, capturing the digit needed from the original header tag into the `$1` variable. During the substitution portion, is there a way I can use that variable to create the needed number of `=` signs (e.g., `"=" x $1`)?

`perl -0777 -pe 's/<h(\d)>([^<]*)<\/h\d>/"="x$1 $2 "="x$1/gs'`, but the latter half (`"="x$1 $2 "="x$1`) of the command doesn't give me the wanted output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operators are not interpolated in strings. You need the `/e` switch to interpret the replacement as code, not just string:

```
s/<h(\d)>([^<]*)<\/h\d>/"=" x $1 . $2 . "=" x $1/ge
```

You can also use a different delimiter instead of `/` to avoid the need to backslash it in `</h`.

`/s` is not needed, as it changes the behaviour of `.` which doesn't occur in the regex.

Comment: Thank you.  Makes perfect sense.  I didn't know about the `/s` changing `.` I'll have to refresh my regex operations a bit more.  Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

That's what the `s///e` [regex modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) is for:

```
s/<h(\d)>([^<]*)<\/h\d>/("=" x $1) .$2. ("=" x $1)/gse
```

Comment: Thank you, looks like you and @choroba were both right on top of this one!  Appreciate the quick turnaround.

Answer (score 0):

This version uses a {} delimeter to avoid escape-itis, a /i and a backreference so something like

```
<h1>.....</h3>
```

doesn't get matched.

```
s{<h(\d)>([^<]*)</h\g1>}{"=" x $1 . " $2 " . "=" x $1}gei;
```